# Best practice for using parentheses in Python function returns?

Tags: python, function, syntax, return, parentheses

I'm learning Python and, so far, I absolutely love it. Everything about it.

I just have one question about a seeming inconsistency in function returns, and I'm interested in learning the logic behind the rule.

If I'm returning a literal or variable in a function return, no parentheses are needed:

```
def fun_with_functions(a, b):
    total = a + b
    return total
```

However, when I'm returning the result of another function call, the function is wrapped around a set of parentheses. To wit:

```
 def lets_have_fun():
     return(fun_with_functions(42, 9000))
```

This is, at least, the way I've been taught, using the [A Smarter Way to Learn Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1974431479) book. I came across this discrepancy and it was given without an explanation. You can see the online exercise [here](http://asmarterwaytolearn.com/python/50.html) (skip to Exercize 10).

Can someone explain to me why this is necessary? Is it even necessary in the first place? And are there other similar variations in parenthetical syntax that I should be aware of?

*Edit: I've rephrased the title of my question to reflect the responses. Returning a result within parentheses is not mandatory, as I originally thought, but it is generally considered best practice, as I have now learned.*

Comment: "Mandatory" is a strong word here - it appears entirely a stylistic preference of that particular author. I've never heard of/seen such a syntax, and it is certainly not necessary. If you are interested in actual style guidelines for Python, check out [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Consequently, PEP 8 contains examples of returning function results without using parentheses.

Comment: One of the commenters below mentioned that a return embedded in parentheses would return a tuple -- so there may be more than just a stylistic difference here.

Comment: No, you *can* return a tuple, like `('text', functionCall())`, but that is no different than referencing that tuple in an earlier variable and returning that variable. But for the case of simply wrapping a function call in parentheses, there is no functional (!) difference.

Comment: @ChristianPerry as I just commented on that answer, the parentheses have no role in returning a tuple there (though visually they help because you're probably more likely to spot the comma). The only thing necessary is the comma; `return "something",` would also return a tuple.

Comment: @jack6e Interesting. Do you have an external resource that you can point me to that would help me understand this better? I'm coming from JavaScript, so tuples are still sinking in.

Comment: Generally, avoid superfluous parentheses in Python, they just add visual clutter. It's OK to use them to make the precedence clear when using the less common operators. And they are the preferred way to allow a long expression to span more than one line.

Comment: If you want to use unnecessary parentheses around the return value, that's up to you, but if you do do that, _please_ leave a space after the `return` keyword so that it doesn't look like a function call. The same applies to the condition expression of `if` and `while` statements.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Gotcha. Thanks for the additional clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary. The parentheses are used for several reason, one reason it's for code style:

`example = some_really_long_function_name() or another_really_function_name()`

so you can use:

```
example = (some_really_long_function_name()
           or
           another_really_function_name())
```

Another use it's like in maths, to force evaluation precede. So you want to ensure the excute between parenthese before. I imagine that the functions return the result of another one, it's just best practice to ensure the execution of the first one but it's no necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! This makes sense. I've edited the title of the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is mandatory. Tried in both python2 and python3, and a without function defined without parentheses in `lets_have_fun()` return clause works just fine. So as jack6e says, it's just a preference.

Answer (score 0):

if you

```
return ("something,)   # , is important, the ( ) are optional, thx @roganjosh
```

you are returning a tuple.

If you are returning

```
return someFunction(4,9)
```

or

```
return (someFunction(4,9))
```

makes no difference. To test, use:

```
def f(i,g):    
    return i * g

def r():    
    return f(4,6)

def q():
    return (f(4,6))

print (type(r()))
print (type(q()))
```

Output:

```
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
```

Comment: To return a tuple the comma is definitely important; it's the only thing needed to define the tuple, so the parentheses are still not necessary in that case. `return "something",` would work just the same